# Custom module conditional configuration optons

Tags: xml, magento, system.xml

I would like to programmatically enable  or disable specific options for a custom module on the administration panel depending on the status of a select. For example, if I had a Yes/No select something like

```
do you want to handle stuffs? < select yes/no >
```

and if stuffs == yes, then a number of other configuration fields would be enabled/visible.  If stuffs != yes then those fields would be disabled/invisible.

Is that possible to do programmatically via `system.xml`/some-other-means, or it is a sci-fi dream?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is definitely functionality that can be handled in Magento. You may want to read up on how to setup configuration options for your module. After you've done that, feel free to ask specific questions if you hit walls.

Comment: Pretty vague, it is something that I've already done, and currently I'm still looking links from google about, that is why I've asked here, I can't find a solution to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You're interested in the `<depends>` tag in `system.xml`.  You can read up about it [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial) (self link).  The general idea is you can make the appearance of a field *depend* on another field containing a specific value.

Comment: Side note: if you need show/hide block, etc. depending on config value, in your layout update file you should use ifconfig attribute: `<block type="rss/list" name="head_rss" ifconfig="rss/config/active" />`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento EE 1.9.1.1 and, when using `<depends>` within a widget, I had to provide a `<value>` tag that encapsulates the value for the dependency. Just a heads up for anyone who is interested in adding dependencies for their widgets.

You can view [my question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3756/widgets-field-dependencies-generate-warning-and-do-not-work) that covers the issue I was having without the `<value>` tag.

The final dependency xml path looked like this:

```
<depends>
    <group_type>
        <value>value to match here</value>
    </group_type>
</depends>
```