# Conditional visibility of configuration field based on magento configuration

Tags: magento, configuration, conditional-statements

I'm building a custom module with it's own configuration tabs, sections and fields. So here's the thing:
I have a select field. Based on the value of that select I'd like to show another field or hide it. I know that this is done as follows:

```
<depends><parentfieldname>value</parentfieldname></depends>
```

How is it possible to allow for multiple values? I've tried the following:

```
<!-- two field-specifying tags, field appears ONLY when 'bananas' is selected -->
<depends><fruit>apples</fruit><fruit>bananas</fruit></depends>

<!-- two 'depends' tags, field appears ONLY when 'bananas' is selected -->
<depends><fruit>apples</fruit></depends>
<depends><fruit>bananas</fruit></depends>

<!-- doesn't work, field won't appear -->
<depends><fruit>apples,bananas</fruit></depends>

<!-- doesn't work, field won't appear -->
<depends><fruit>apples|bananas</fruit></depends>
```

I [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679348/custom-module-conditional-configuration-optons) before asking this question, pretty much the same but then applied to multiple values. I suppose a multiselect field could have a value like 'apples,bananas', but I'm looking for a way to allow for value1 OR value2, not value1 AND value2.

Comment: try this [Multiple Condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849616/can-a-magento-adminhtml-field-depend-on-more-then-one-field-or-value)

Comment: also, I got it an information which is specified `<frontend_type>` tag should be `select`, did you tried that?

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I already had `select` as the field's type, but thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the separator param like bellow

`<depends>
    <fruit separator=",">apples,bananas</fruit>
</depends>`

Comment: I haven't done any magento development in a while, but I will try soon, thanks! If it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: doesnt work for widget. The separator functionality works only in system config.